# Omit properties from nested TypeScript interface

Tags: typescript

I have the following TypeScript interfaces:

```
export interface Customer {
  id: string;
  accountId: string;
  name?: string;
  offices?: Office[];
}

export interface Office {
  id: string;
  name?: string;
  country?: string;
  address?: string;
  zip?: string;
  description?: string;
  workplaces: Workplace[];
}

export interface Workplace {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  employeeId?: string;
}
```

My Goal is to use `<Customer>` but without the `Workplace.id` and `Workplace.name`.

So I tried to create a new interface and to `Omit` those two properties like this but it is not working as it still needs the two props:

```
export interface AddCustomer
  extends Customer,
    Office,
    Omit<Workplace, 'id' | 'name'> {}
```

The outcome should be this Object of type AddCustomer:

```
const addCustomerDetail: AddCustomer = {
   id: '123',
   accountId: '123',
   name: 'some name',
   offices: [
      {
         id: '123',
         name: 'some name',
         country: 'UK',
         address: 'Street name',
         zip: '90210',
         description: 'Some Office'
         workplaces: [
            {
               employeeId: '1337'
            }
         ]
      }  
   ]
}
```

Comment: Do you need to do this programmatically? If so you could write a `DeepReplace` utility type to help, and use it like [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/N5VAZm) shows.  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Thats a really clever solution with `DeepReplace`, @jcalz!
Unfortunately I get the following type error at office.id: `Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'id' does not exist in type 'Omit<Workplace, "id" | "name">'.`

Comment: Yeah, you omitted it.  Did you want to do something else? This looks like a followup issue that you ran into after you solved this problem.  As such it might be better to disentangle it from the question as asked, rather than expand the scope to include the next problem you hit.  Do you agree and I should just write up my suggestion in an answer? Or do you disagree and want to [edit] with a [mre] that demonstrates your actual issue (not that I can commit to responding if the scope changes)?

Comment: Sorry then I completely misunderstood the use-case for `Omit`. My understanding was that with this I can remove properties from a type. To better follow my question I added an example outcome what I want to achieve. I hope this now makes it completely understandable! @jcalz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using generics to define the Workplace you want to have?
Let's start by defining two Workplace interfaces and inherit one of them:

```
export interface BaseWorkplace {
  employeeId?: string;
}

export interface FullWorkplace extends BaseWorkplace {
  id: string;
  name: string;
}
```

Then, an Office with a generic Workplace property, default set as a `FullWorkplace` so you don't need to explicitly pass the generic every time you need the `Office`:

```
export interface Office<T extends BaseWorkplace = FullWorkplace> {
  id: string;
  name?: string;
  country?: string;
  address?: string;
  zip?: string;
  description?: string;
  // Here, using T as property type
  workplaces: T[];
}
```

The you could follow downwards the hierarchy chain:

```
export interface Customer<T extends BaseWorkplace = FullWorkplace> {
  id: string;
  accountId: string;
  name?: string;
  offices?: Office<T>[];
}
```

And finally define your `addCustomerDetail`:

```
export interface AddCustomer extends Customer<BaseWorkplace>{};

const addCustomerDetail: AddCustomer = {
  id: '123',
  accountId: '123',
  name: 'some name',
  offices: [
     {
        id: '123',
        name: 'some name',
        country: 'UK',
        address: 'Street name',
        zip: '90210',
        description: 'Some Office',
        workplaces: [
           {
              employeeId: '1337'
           }
        ]
     }  
  ]
}
```

If you do not want to propagate that generic `T` down the hierarchy, you could instead define a base `AddCustomer` and extending it in `Customer`:

```
export interface AddCustomer {
  id: string;
  accountId: string;
  name?: string;
  offices?: Office<BaseWorkplace>[];
};

export interface Customer extends AddCustomer {
  // This works because FullWorkplace extends BaseWorkplace, doing the opposite will result in an error
  offices?: Office<FullWorkplace>[];
}
```